Transferring a file with ymodem over TCP network
I have a device (RELAY) I am able to telnet into using its IP address from an linux machine (CLIENT) and I'd like to copy a file from the RELAY to the CLIENT. I have very limited privileges on RELAY, but I can view a list of files on it with file dir, and then I should be able to download a file from it using YModem, per the manufacturer, who instructed that the command to send the file is
file read filename.ext

After typing that it displays
> #000 Ready to send file

but I'm not sure how to set up a method to receive the file on CLIENT I have full access to. I've read in this post to receive using minicom, but that appears to be for a serial connection and I'm doing this over a TCP network. I've tried with sz as well and tried to use the --tcp options, but again am not sure if it's simply me not understanding which options to use or if this method isn't correct.
What are possible methods for me to connect to RELAY from CLIENT and tell it I'm ready to receive the file?
(edit) I had a request to edit this question about why it's different than the one I linked to, and the reason it's different is that for my application I'm using telnet over TCP and the previously linked discussion is using a serial connection.

This question is similar to: File transfer using YMODEM sz. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is different to the one suggested by @ChrisDavies because this is about using xyz-modem protocol over a telnet connection, not a serial line.

One way to do this is to connect telnet with the rb command via
expect, linking the two pseudo-terminals ("pty").
On my Fedora system, rb is included with sz in the package lrzsz,
containing zmodem (*z), ymodem (*b), and xmodem (*x),  send (s*)
and receive (r*) commands.
This is the expect script I tried with a dummy telnet server that might
approximate what your RELAY is doing:
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn telnet localhost 4444
set telnetid $spawn_id
interact -o  "Ready to send " return
puts "saw prompt, starting rb"
spawn rb --verbose --rename
set rbid $spawn_id
set spawn_id $telnetid
interact -u $rbid
puts "end of rb. continue typing"
interact 

The first spawn command runs telnet to the remote.
Here you will need to change my testing localhost 4444 to RELAY.
We remember the pty connection id in variable telnetid.
The first interact then copies everything you type to the telnet process,
and prints anything received from it. (Use this to login.) It is transparent until you type in a
command (eg file read ...) that results in the string "Ready to send "
being sent back to you over telnet. When it matches, the interact stops.
The puts command prints a message to you.
The second spawn runs rb, creating a new pty connection saved in
variable rbid. We restore the global spawn_id to be the telnet process so
we can use interact to transfer data between it and the rb process.
This interaction should normally terminate with rb stopping and closing
the connection, causing an eof. In principle, the remote should also have
finished the file read command, and so the last interact allows you to
talk with telnet until you close the connection.
Be careful with the expect syntax, it can be delicate. For further debug add  -d to the first line, and see man expect, and man rb. For further problems, please post them as separate questions.

To debug further, replace the spawn rb command by
spawn strace -o /tmp/out rb

and at the end you will get a large file /tmp/out showing each system call made. Here are some relevant lines from my test which transferred a file called testfile:
write(1, "C", 1)                        = 1
ioctl(0, TCFLSH, TCIFLUSH)              = 0
rt_sigaction(...
alarm(10)                               = 0
read(0, "\1\0\377testfile\00029 14707636223 10064"..., 8192) = 133
alarm(0)                                = 10
write(1, "\6", 1)                       = 1
openat(AT_FDCWD, "testfile", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "testfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
...
write(3, "...", 29) = 29
close(3)                                = 0
...
chmod("testfile", 0644)                 = 0

Each line ends with = and a number. This is the return code of the system
call, typically 0 for ok, and -1 for an error.
The lines beginning read(0 show data coming from the telnet connection,
and write(1 is data going to telnet. write(2 are messages to stderr you
should have seen. In these calls, the return code is the number of bytes
actually read or written.
The openat(AT_FDCWD, "...", ...) line shows the name of the file being
opened, and AT_FDCWD means it is in the current directory, assuming the
filename does not begin with "/".  There will be many of these early on in
the file which can be ignored; they are loading shared libraries.
The openat we are interested in has flag O_CREAT, and is for the
"testfile" that will hold the received data. It is preceded by another
openat: this first open of "testfile" returns an error; it is testing to
see if the file exists already, so as not to overwrite it. The second
openat has option O_CREAT and creates the file. The return code of 3 is
the file descriptor for writes.
Data accepted by rb is written to the file with one or more write(3,
lines. The file is closed, close(3), and a chmod is done on it.

Can you get ! command to work ? I find it always returns ?Invalid command (ubuntu 20.04)

@XTian ! works ok on Fedora 38. I suppose it might have been removed for security in some versions.

I tried this and was able to run it using my relay IP and port 23. It seems to process exactly as you mention, allowing me to login once connected, issue the file read ... command, and then it spawns rb and eventually rb ends as indicated and I can then exit the telnet session. My only question is - where is the file saved or what is it named? I don't see anything in the local directory where I'm running the script from and have searched for the filename and can't find it.

I would have expected it to create a file in the current directory. If you typed file read SOME/PATH/THEFILE.EXT,I would expect you to get file some_path_thefile.ext in the directory you ran the expect script in. This is according to the rb man page, but it seems the sender can choose what filename to use with the ymodem protocol. The --rename option at least should stop it overwriting any existing file. It should add a number suffix to make a unique name.

Were you able to get this to work and create a file? I've tried a few different rb commands but I never see a file created (although it does take a few seconds for the rb command to complete, so it does seem like some sort of transfer is happening).

Yes, I received a file; on the server I used sb -v sender/testfile and on the receiver I got a file testfile. You might try configuring the telnet connection after you login, but before running rb. Use control-[ to get the prompt "telnet> " then enter the 2 lines (ending with enter) "mode char" and "set binary". Return to the connection with an empty line. I tend to use these settings all the time, and did so in my tests.

I've added a way to debug further what rb is doing.

Install socat. Create a PTY connection to your target host and its telnet port coupled to a local socket. Connect minicom to the local socket.
Worked example

My equivalent to your RELAY host, except mine is running a shell on port 12345 rather than a telnet daemon on port 23. You don't need this, but the worked example requires it:
socat TCP-LISTEN:12345,fork,reuseaddr EXEC:'/bin/bash',PTY,stderr,rawer


The intermediary. You should change references of localhost port 12345 to your RELAY port 23
socat PTY,link="$HOME/vmodem0",rawer,wait-slave EXEC:"nc localhost 12345"


The minicom application itself. Run this on the same host as the intermediary code:
minicom -p "$(readlink "$HOME/vmodem0")"




I ran 2 with my RELAY IP and port 23, then 3 at which point I was connected to the RELAY terminal and could enter the login command, password, and eventually file read ... at which point it gives me the same #000 Ready to send file but no file transfer begins. Is there another step I'm missing to begin copying the file or do I need to run something else before #3?

You need to interact with minicom to launch the ymodem protocol. Type the character control-A, then capital R, and you should see a protocol  menu. Use the arrow keys and enter to select ymodem.

After those additional commands it says rb waiting to receive. then every few seconds it will say Retry 0: CRC then Retry 1: CRC, etc. Is there another minicom setting I need to adjust?
